# How to identify which hdd to be replaced in RAID

Tags: raid, raid5, hard-drive

Our RAID5 (using Adaptec 3085) stopped working because one of the hdd is broken. How can I identify which one it is?

[image]

Comment: If your RAID5 stopped because of ONE disk failure... you may have a more serious problem than you think.

Comment: Maybe you can elaborate more on that ...

Comment: @Radek: RAID5 has redundancy for one disk. It *should* keep going with just a single disk broken.

Comment: But the disk should be replaced, right. How to identify which one.

Comment: What kind of system is this? Most server-grade hardware has a fault light on the HD that will illuminate when the controller marks it as failed...

Comment: Radak: You can't drill into the config to identify the `disks` or `physical disks` versus that of the `array` or `span` or even `logical disk` or `logical volume`?  No idea?  Follow the [user guide](http://download.adaptec.com/pdfs/user_guides/Adaptec_RAID_Controller_IUG_08_2008.pdf) (page 63 is a good place to start)

Comment: Our admin didn't know how to solve so I was trying to help out. I don't know any more details. So maybe even the wording of the my question is not exact. @mbrownnyc could you create an answer from your comment?

Comment: No lights showing on the drives? It's normal for the drive carriers to have lights and if one of those is red you've found your bad drive.

Comment: Thanks Radek.  That wasn't an answer though.  InChargeOfIT (punny guy) seems to have an answer and the best/only answer.

Comment: Quite often comments are also the best answers....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to install the Adaptec Storage Manager software to make the LED on the drive blink, but...

like Gregory said, the system should not have failed if one drive went bad.. that is the point of a RAID 5. My guess would be you have an issue with your controller, the attached storage device, cabling, or you got very unlucky and had two drives fail. If the host OS is running, try the ASM and rebuild.

ASM Download for your card: http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/downloads/storage_manager/sm/productid=sas-3085&dn=adaptec+raid+3085.html

Also download the user manual: http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/support/raid/sas_raid/sas-5405/_docs/asm_v6_00_users_guide_for_das_pdf.htm?nc=/en-us/support/raid/sas_raid/sas-5405/_docs/asm_v6_00_users_guide_for_das_pdf.htm

Comment: The drives don't have LED's on them. There are LED's on the card though.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot identify drives with LED's try to get the serial number of the broken drive or in bad case the serial numbers of the sane drives. They are also printed on the drive it self.

A) If you can and want to boot:

A1) Linux Terminal (assuming 1 is your controller number):
check drives with: `# arcconf GETLOGS 1 DEVICE tabular|less`

find dead drives with: `# arcconf GETLOGS 1 DEAD tabular|less`

A2) The Adaptec Storage Manager is great GUI for many OS and has network support.

B) You cannot boot the OS

B1) The controler bios should also support details to the drives but it is limited

B2) search for a rescue CD or USB image with A1 or A2

Find actual "arcconf" or "Adaptec Storage Manager" here:
http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/search.html

Good links to that issue also for software raid and other controllers:
http://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Seriennummern_von_Festplatten_und_Hinweise_zu_defekten_Festplatten/en